# What are some options for handling image uploading/compression in ASP?

Tags: image-processing, asp-classic, image-resizing, image-compression

please bear with me as I'm not trying to frustrate anyone with inane questions, and I did google search this but I couldn't really find anything recent or helpful.

I am a novice programmer and I am using a classic asp web application. I just enabled the users to upload and download images, but I'm quickly regretting it as it's eating up all of the router bandwidth. I am finding my solution inadequate, so I wanted to start over.

My desire is threefold with this functionality:

1. Compression. I understand that this is impossible to do BEFORE uploading without some kind of Java/Silverlight/Flash portion of the application to handle uploads, correct? What is the common way most places go about this? Just allow regular file uploads and compress once they are on the server?
2. Resizing. I want to resize all images before they are uploaded to a reasonable size, instead of just telling users that try and upload huge camera images that they can't upload. I figure I just want to let them upload and have it resize for them before uploading. Does this functionality exist already?
3. Changing filetype. I want to allow users to upload all image file types but make them .jpg on the server after the upload.

With these three requirements, how hard is it to implement something like this in just pure code and libraries? Would it be better to just use a 3rd party plugin, such as ASPjpeg or ASPupload? Have you encountered something similar, and what was your solution?

Thanks.

Comment: for 1), consider this: if you want the server to compress the image, then by definition it has to have the original UNCOMPRESSED image to work with, which means you have to upload that original uncompressed image data. 2) ditto for resizing. if the server does the resizing, it has to have the original full-size image to work with. as for 3) that's trivial. once you have the image file on your server, it can be converted to any other supported type. that's a simple X->Y re-encoding.

Comment: Your only option is to do the image manipulation before you send the upload, there a lot of good JavaScript libraries out there that provide this type of functionality. Would research "JavaScript Image Manipulation Libraries" or "JavaScript Image Upload" *(a lot of upload libraries have resizing baked in)*.

Comment: You can use a third party image hosting same way Stack Exchange themselves are doing. SE use imgur, which provides API for this. Doubt you'll find something for free, but if paying is an option, that's your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ASPJpeg](http://aspjpeg.com) and [ASPUpload](http://aspupload.com) from Persits. We use these components to upload a full size image (can be png even though the library is "ASPJpeg"), resize it to several different sizes we need on our site, then store the resized images on the server in a variety of folders. The ASPUpload component is a little tricky but if you follow their sample code you'll be fine.

I never found a good component for decompressing uploaded zip files and had to write my own, which I've since abandoned. In the end with upload speeds increasing and storage getting so cheap, it started to matter less and less that the files were compressed before being uploaded.

EDIT: Just noticed you mentioned these components in your question. Consider this an endorsement of your idea to use them. :-)

Comment: This is the solution I recommend to anyone coming into this topic. For what it's worth, I ended up creating an entire custom upload tool using a jquery front end to manage file sizes and a web service backend that receives the file chunks and uploads them one at a time. That took two weeks of work, however, so I believe just using a third party software would be cheaper.